# dot.com/car1 does work, but dot.com/transport/car1 doesn’t work

Tags: menus

index.php

```
$args = array(
 'posts_per_page' => 5,
 'orderby' => 'post_date',
 'order' => 'DESC',
 'post_type' => array('car', 'bus', 'boat'), //plugin pods
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
while($query->have_posts()) {
  $query->the_post();
  echo '<a href="' . get_permalink(get_the_ID()) . '">'
   .get_the_title()
   ."</a>";
 }
```

1) http://www.dot.com/car1 (and dot.com/car2, dot.com/bus1…)
and http://www.dot.com

This works.

2) http://www.dot.com/transport/car1 (and dot.com/transport/car2, dot.com/transport/bus1…)
and http://www.dot.com/transport

This doesn’t work: 404 error.

I have tried “transport” here: (Categories) wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category
and also here: (Permalinks) wp-admin/options-permalink.php http://www.dot.com/%category%
but it doens’t work

Ex. This does work: http://www.dot.com/car and http://www.dot.com/boat

OR http://www.dot.com/car/car1 and http://www.dot.com/boat/boat7

This does not work: http://www.dot.com/transport

OR http://www.dot.com/transport/car1 and http://www.dot.com/transport/boat7

Anyone know?

Comment: try setting permalinks to `/%category%/%postname%/` and saving, instead of just `/%category`

Comment: Custom post type URLs are controlled by the the `rewrite` argument when the post types are registered. Edit your question and add your code that registers your post types. If you use a plugin to create these post types, then you may need to ask the plugin developer for help, 3rd party plugins are off-topic here.